# Making sense of 1-dimensional data

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I am collecting data of individual people. Each data is one dimensional, indicating a time difference of them doing certain things. Each person requires a different time value measured in miliseconds to do a certain task, in this case - typing on the keyboard.

I have a vector of these values. **What type of metrics would be a good indicator to distinguish people from each other?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use different kernels. See a list of kernels here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)
You can also use many different kernels like wavelets depending on what sort of information you're interested in.